# How to update R on Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, r

I am not able to update R version 3.* on 4.*

What I have done according to this [page](https://medium.com/@hpgomide/how-to-update-your-r-3-x-to-the-r-4-x-in-your-linux-ubuntu-46e2209409c3):

```
I checked /etc/apt/sources.list

#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 19.2 Tina - Release amd64 20190729]/ bionic contrib main non-free
```

I ran:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
[sudo] heslo pro linux:    
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.H9fjVZrS2l/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: klíč 51716619E084DAB9: „Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>“ 1 nový podpis
gpg: Celkový počet zpracovaných klíčů: 1
gpg:         nové podpisy: 1
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt install r-base
Načítají se seznamy balíků… Hotovo
Vytváří se strom závislostí       
Načítají se stavové informace… Hotovo
r-base je již nejnovější verze (3.4.4-1ubuntu1).
Následující balíky byly nainstalovány automaticky a již nejsou potřeba:
  libllvm9 linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-128-generic linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-128-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-128-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic
Pro jejich odstranění použijte „sudo apt autoremove“.
0 aktualizováno, 0 nově instalováno, 0 k odstranění a 245 neaktualizováno.
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt install r-base
Načítají se seznamy balíků… Hotovo
Vytváří se strom závislostí       
Načítají se stavové informace… Hotovo
r-base je již nejnovější verze (3.4.4-1ubuntu1).
Následující balíky byly nainstalovány automaticky a již nejsou potřeba:
  libllvm9 linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-128-generic linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-128-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-128-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic
Pro jejich odstranění použijte „sudo apt autoremove“.
0 aktualizováno, 0 nově instalováno, 0 k odstranění a 245 neaktualizováno.
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ r -- version

Příkaz 'r' nebyl nalezen, ale je možné jej nainstalovat pomocí:

sudo apt install r-cran-littler

linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

The version is still 3.4.4.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: does running apt update help? I'm new to mint, and I could be mistaken.

Comment: No, I ran the R Studio and I wrote the >> version there - the result was the same 3.*

Comment: Can you run apt update, then try to install R with apt install r-base?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output in English so we can understand it. You can get English output by adding the `LC_ALL=C` before each command. For example: `LC_ALL=C sudo apt install r-base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focal` won't work for you, you are on `bionic` (Linux Mint Tina is based on Ubuntu bionic).

Remove focal repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'
```

add bionic-cran40:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'
```

then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
```

Comment: Thank you very much